# My code runs on Spyder but it doesn't run on Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I've encountered with an interesting problem. I want to read frames of a video. I can do it using Spyder.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('t.mp4')
print('before video')
# loop over frames from the video stream
while cap.isOpened():
    print('it is in video')
```

When I try to run it from Anaconda prompt using

```
python read_video.py
```

I see this as output:

```
before video
```

So, It doesn't enter in while loop. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 't.mp4' could not be opened

```
cap.isOpened() is False
```

Your should verify first, that the file actually exists, e.g. using pathlib

```
Path('t.mp4').exists()
```